# Format XML from B2B into HTML on the fly

Tags: xml, formatting, b2b

I am new to XML and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on this. So an order comes in from our partner company, B2B turns it into XML and gives it back to us. It would more then likely just end up in a folder somewhere on our server or maybe the mailbox. We need to render each individual XML into a nice looking packing slip. The packing slips would be identical except for the fact that the logo would need to be changed depending on what store it came from.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a really broad question, much like "how do I build a house?" and there is really not enough specific information here to help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

use XSLT filter for the XML to HTML transformation (google XSL stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

Designing the overall application architecture is too broad a topic for this forum. However, the XML-to-HTML conversion is readily achieved using XSLT.